# Preventing Ethereum Wallet to download binaries

Tags: mist, wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp

On Windows 10, I have a separate geth.exe running with custom configuration. But when I run Ethereum Wallet (0.8.10.1708) it downloads new binaries.
Is there a way to prevent it from doing that?
THX.